# Website visitor message sending and receiving destination

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to figure out how to send website visitor message to administrator from "send message" form on page.

For example in verification scenario user receives confirmation message from my web mail:

```
$headers .= 'From: <adminemail@email.com>' . "\r\n";
```

to his email:

```
$to = 'useremail@email.com';
```

I'm not sure, how to send and receive visitor message:

```
 $to = 'adminemail@email.com';
```

from:

```
$headers .= 'From: <adminemail@email.com>' . "\r\n";
```

via admin email to admin email and receiving visitor email for further answer just as message  `$mail` together with `$message`, or I could use visitor email as sender:

```
$to = 'adminemail@email.com';
```

from:

```
$headers .= 'From: <visitormail@email.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Any guide or advise would be useful

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @mittmemo Hello, I'm trying to figure out with destination addresses from/to with website visitor message sending and receiving by administrator in send message form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set the `From` email to the visitors email, as this will get your server flagged from sending spam (since the email isn't really from the visitor).

Instead, you should set the `From` email to one on your domain (ex. form@domain.com) and set the `Reply-To` to the visitors email. This way, when you reply to the email it will go to the visitor correctly.

For example:

```
From: <form@mydomain.com>
Reply-To: <visitormail@email.com>
To: My Name <adminemail@email.com>
```